# Specific server IP using winsock

Tags: c++, tcp, winsock2

I need some help

Last week I wrote my first server application in C++ using winsock2 by following a tutorial.
This tutorial does not connect to a specific IP, but using a tool called "SocketTest" I can connect to the server via IP 127.0.0.1 and port 21.

I would like to use a specific IP address (192.168.1.10) and port (17013).
I know how to do the port but I son't know how to connect to a specific IP address.
Could anyone help me and explain it to me?
This is the code I use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

void main()
{

    //initialize winsock (sockets)
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Can't initialize winsock! quitting" << endl;
        return;
    }

    //create a socket
    SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create a socket! quitting" << endl;
        return;
    }

    //bind the ip to a socket address and port
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(21);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY; //could also use inet_pton

    bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));

    //tell winsock the socket is for listening
    listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);

    //wait for a connection
    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);

    SOCKET clientSocket = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't make connection! quitting" << endl;
        return;
    }

    char host[NI_MAXHOST];      //client's remote name
    char service[NI_MAXSERV];   //service (i.e. port) the client is connect on

    ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST);
    ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXSERV);

    if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0)
    {
        cout << host << " connected on port " << service << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
        cout << host << " connected on port " <<
            ntohs(client.sin_port) << endl;
    }

    //close listening socket
    closesocket(listening);

    char buf[4096];

    while (true) //this part of the code will be used to send and receive data
    {
        ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
        float X = 12.4;
        float Y = 456;
        float Z = 900.87;

        sprintf_s(buf, "(%lf,%lf,%lf)",X,Y,Z);
        size_t buf_len = strlen(buf);

        send(clientSocket, buf, buf_len, 0);




        int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);
    }

    //close the socket(s)
    closesocket(clientSocket);

    //shutdown/cleanup winsock (sockets)
    WSACleanup();

}
```

Comment: This is server code? So the IP is the IP of your computer, not of the program

Comment: Connecting is a client operation. This is server code. There is nothing here that connects to anything. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Yes this is the server code, I am trying to communicate with a UR5 robot via an Ethernet connection and send some float values to it. On this UR5 robot I open a socket by doing: "open_socket("127.0.0.1",21), but this doesn't seem to work. But i gues this IP in "open_socket" is wrong then?

Comment: And the problem is? The clients don't care that you're listening at INADDR_ANY.

Comment: The problem really is that I can't get the UR5e robot to connect to my PC(server). I have connected it via an Ethernet cable, I think I've gotten my IP address wrong (I need to give the IP of the PC(server) to the robot right?). But I don't really know how I get the correct IP.

Comment: That problem has nothing to do with INADDR_ANY whatsoever. You're barking up the wrong tree. You might have the wrong IP address to configure the device to connect to, or the wrong port, or you might have a LAN topology problem. Can you ping the device from the server host? You can find out your own IP address easily enough. Is that your real question?

Comment: Yes I have been able to ping the device from the server host, using ping(IP-address) in a command prompt. The IP I give the robot to connect to I find using the ipconfig command and then pick the IPv4 located under Ethernet adapter. The port on the robot is set to 21. Is this the right way to do it, or am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: Sounds right to me, if the device is connected via Ethernet and expects to connect to port 21.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong in my robot program then. I'll post something on UR's own forum. Anyway, Thank you I think I understand I a little better now. Sorry if my initial questions where absolutely stupid, I am just starting with this networking stuff.